# размер сайта на хостинге и на локалке разный

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Столкнулся с проблемой сверстал сайт и на локалке все норм а когда загружаю на хостинг сайт шире окна браузера в чем может быть причина на сколько я заметил весь сайт немного увеличивается на хостинге

Comment: От хостинга "размер сайта" зависеть не может

Comment: Может у вас масштаб страницы больше чем на локальном?

Comment: в чем же может быть причина код на хостинге и локалке идентичны

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зайдите на проблемный сайт и сбросьте масштаб в браузере к исходному. Например, в хроме это сочетание клавиш `Ctrl + 0` (или `⌘ + 0` для Mac OS X). Масштаб вполне может сохранять выбранное значение для конкретного домена, поэтому на локалке отображение может быть одним, а на хостинге другим (масштабированным).

Comment: спасибо помогло